# ag-grid How to drag whole parent column when dragging child column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have a grid similar to this:
[image: Grid with child and parent column headers]

ag-grid by default allows you to drag individual child columns (like 'Game Name' or 'Bought') out from the parent column, splitting the parent into two. What I want to do is to disable this behaviour, so that when you try to drag the child column like 'Bought', it will instead drag the whole 'Game of Choice' column and both of its children.

If this is not doable, is there a way to disable dragging of just the children but keep dragging of the parent enabled?

Comment: Actually, better you share your code. Cause the volunteers will solve it with their codes.

Comment: @GilangPratama Thanks, but this is independent of my code though, this is just a general question of how to implement this using ag-grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking something like below.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/#grouping-example-with-marrychildren-set

> Marry Children
>
> Sometimes you want columns of the group to always stick together. To achieve this, set the column group property marryChildren=true. The
> example below demonstrates the following:
>
> - Both 'Athlete Details' and 'Sports Results' have marryChildren=true.
> - If you move columns inside these groups, you will not be able to move    the column out of the group. For example, if you drag
>   'Athlete', it    is not possible to drag it out of the 'Athlete
>   Details' group.
> - If you move a non group column, eg 'Extra 3', it will not be possible    to place it in the middle of a group and hence impossible
>   to break    the group apart.
> - It is possible to place a column between groups (eg you can place    'Extra 3' between the 'Athlete Details' and 'Sports Results').

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I have been trying to find. Thank you very much!